# Django manager with datetime.timedelta object inside F query combined with annotate and filter

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-managers

I am trying to create manager method inside my app, to filter emails object, that have been created 5/10/15 minutes or what so ever, counting exactly from now.

I though I'am gonna use annotate to create new parameter, which will be bool and his state depends on simple subtraction with division and checking if the result is bigger than 0.

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.utils import timezone


delta = 60 * 1 * 5
current_date = timezone.now()
qs = self.annotate(passed=((current_date - F('created_at')).seconds // delta > 0)).filter(passed=True)
```

Atm my error says:
`AttributeError: 'CombinedExpression' object has no attribute 'seconds'`

It is clearly happening duo the fact, that `((current_date - F('created_at'))` does not evaluate to `datetime.timedelta` object but to the CombinedExpression object.

I see more problems out there, i.e. how to compare the expression to 0?

Anyway, would appreciate any tips if I am somewhere close to achieve my goal or is my entire logic behind this query incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to find the solution, even though it might not be the elegant one, it works

`qs = self.annotate(foo=Sum(current_date - F('created_at'))).filter(foo__gt=Sum(timezone.timedelta(seconds=delta)))`

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

```
time_cut_off = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(minutes=delta)
qs = self.filter(created_at__gte=time_cut_off)
```

This will get you the messages created in the last *delta* minutes.  Or where you looking for messages created exactly 5 minutes ago (how do you define that if that is the question).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation provides [a simple and elegant solution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) if your timedelta is a constant :

> For date and date/time fields, you can add or subtract a timedelta object. The following would return all entries that were modified more than 3 days after they were published:
>
> ```
> >>> from datetime import timedelta
> >>> Entry.objects.filter(mod_date__gt=F('pub_date') + timedelta(days=3))
> ```

In your case I don't think you even need the `F()` objects.

Comment: For cases in which your timedelta depends on an other field (requires to use a `F()` object), I'm currently searching for a solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729179/datetime-comparison-with-a-timedelta-from-an-f-object