# Datetime comparison with a timedelta from an other field (F() objects)

Tags: python, django, datetime, orm

### Context :

I'm trying to make a condition for a queryset filtering.

It implies 2 fields of my model, one field representing a timedelta (a number of minutes), one field representing a datetime (`start_datetime`), and `datetime.datetime.now()` (aka. `now`).

I'd like to check if `start_datetime - now <= time_delta`.

### General case :

I've seen the example (from the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)) in which we're able to compare two date(time)s and a constant timedelta.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> Entry.objects.filter(mod_date__gt=F('pub_date') + timedelta(days=3))
```

But what if it's a value contained in an other field of my entry?

The way I try to instanciate this timedelta is obviously not permitted.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> Entry.objects.filter(mod_date__gt=F('pub_date') + timedelta(days=F('n_timedelta')))
```

Could there be a solution to achieve this using the ORM features?
I'd like to avoid using some raw SQL as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution.

I struggled too much with different conversions and casts, so I tried an other way:

I applied the filtering condition on the `time_delta` attribute, and used the difference between both dates from which I extracted the number of seconds since EPOCH time, then divided by 60 to get the number of minutes :

Which gave something like :

```
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> from django.db.models.functions import Extract, Now
>>> Entry.objects.filter(
...     time_delta__gte=(Extract(F("start_datetime"), "epoch") - Extract(Now(), "epoch"))/60
... )
```

Comment: Nice Answer. Thanks!